# WordPress limit excerpt length characters don't work

Tags: wordpress

I don't understand why my code don't work in my WordPress thème.
For limit excerpt length characters I add this in my files functions.php :

```
function va_custom_excerpt_length() {
    return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'va_custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

and this in home.php

```
<div class="article-ex">
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div>
```

This code returns all the extract and not 20 characters

TY do much for help. 
Vincent

Comment: check this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/139953/excerpt-length-not-working, it might help you.

Comment: Your code is perfect. you have required to do one change in last parameter. replace 999 to 1.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers

Answer (score 0):

You may also do it by php string function ...

```
$string = get_the_content();
$newString = substr($string, 0, 20);
echo $newString;
```